# How to change the white colour of the 'Move to Trash' option in context menu to red?

Tags: unity, context-menu

Linux Mint displays the 'delete' option in the context menu with a red icon color.

I want to change the color of the corresponding menu item in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

I would like to know where the context menu files are stored in Ubuntu 16.04 so I can edit them to achieve this.

[image: context menu with move to trash (white text) circled]

[image: delete option in context menu with red x symbol]